# Class 'Geocoder\Provider\OpenCage\OpenCage' not found

Tags: php, api, composer-php

I'm trying to translate my long and lat from my html 5 location request into a readable adress. I'm trying to use openCage Geocoding for this but it keeps giving the nex error:

Class 'Geocoder\Provider\OpenCage\OpenCage' not found

this is my code, like [the documentation](https://opencagedata.com/tutorials/geocode-in-php) said

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client as GuzzleAdapter;
use Geocoder\Query\GeocodeQuery;
use Geocoder\Query\ReverseQuery;

$adapter  = new GuzzleAdapter();
$provider = new \Geocoder\Provider\OpenCage\OpenCage($adapter, 'APIKEY');
$geocoder = new \Geocoder\StatefulGeocoder($provider, 'en');

$results = $geocoder->geocodeQuery(GeocodeQuery::create('1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, 94025'));
# print_r($results);

$coords = $results->first()->getCoordinates();

echo json_encode([ 'lat' => $coords->getLatitude(), 'lon' => $coords->getLongitude() ]) . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: Can you share mode details? How did you install that `OpenCage` class? Does the given class exist at the expected folder? Does the autoloader contain this information?

Comment: the documentation said just to install it with this command "composer require opencage/geocode" and then require it in the doc. https://opencagedata.com/tutorials/geocode-in-php

Comment: i'm obviously missing something verry basic, it's the first i'm using something like composer with my code

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you linked to:

> There are two PHP libraries you can use

You have installed one and used the sample code from the other. So, either run this command:

```
composer require willdurand/geocoder
```

And keep using the code above.

Or, replace your code with something like this:

```
$geocoder = new \OpenCage\Geocoder\Geocoder('YOUR-API-KEY');
$result = $geocoder->geocode('1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, 94025');
if ($result && $result['total_results'] > 0) {
    $first = $result['results'][0];
    echo json_encode([
        'lat' => $first['geometry']['lat'],
        'lon' => $first['geometry']['lng'],
    ]);

}
```